# Email Client with Excel-Like Interface

Tags: email, spreadsheet

I am after an e-mail client that lets me add custom columns, and sort and filter e-mails in a way similar to the way Excel works.

I manage a small team of researchers who do interviews with various people.

In my e-mail I get interview transcripts, updates on finding interviewees, deadline agreements, etc.

I currently manage all this by entering the dates and times of all my e-mails into an Excel spreadsheet. I then add new columns for Researcher Name, Topic, Interviewee etc. and quick notes in another column on how the interview went.

Adding the e-mails to the database is time consuming. I would prefer to have custom columns in my e-mail client and add the pertinent information there. I would then like to be able to filter the columns using tickboxes the same way it works in Excel (rather than just sorting them).

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for exists. [EssentialPIM](https://www.essentialpim.com/) allows you to link between different data types, maybe you could link emails to notes containing the desired information. You could also save email files to disk in eml format and use an advanced file manager like [XYPlorer](https://www.xyplorer.com/) that allows custom scripted columns to extract certain information from those eml files, whcih are in essence just text files

Comment: I totally agree that it is extremely likely that you will find such an email client (search for one that lets you add your own columns & sort on them). You would be best advised to investigate [CRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer_relationship_management) software, which is headily used by sales people, recruiters, etc